# Eclipse on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: eclipse

I have problem using eclipse on Ubuntu 16.04 .It takes too much CPU and when I want to create or delete a project or a class , it takes a long time and eclipse goes not responding.
This had never happened to me using windows or Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Open a terminal and run `eclipse` when it opens, do whatever you do to crash it and when it does, edit the output in to your question, if there is a lot of output, paste it here and link it http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: try to disable project build automatically